# Get cpu usage average for the last 5 seconds

Tags: linux, shell, cpu

I am trying to find an alternative to this command:

`mpstat 5 1`

Even though it works as i need, but it have a delay of 5 seconds,
i need something similar, but that will give me instantly the CPU usage average of last 5 seconds.

Comment: Does it need to be the previous 5 seconds from when you run the command?  There's nothing that stores that information, but you can run a background command (like mpstat) that records and stores a 5 second average, and than have another command show that info.

Comment: You can look at the `sar` command but that usually only polls every ten minutes.

Comment: @Brian any suggestion of efficient way to store and reuse that info ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a butt-simple script to record it:

```
while true; do
     mpstat 5 1 > tmpstat
     cp tmpstat laststat
done
```

Then run the above script in the background.  The last `mpstat` will be available immediatley in the file `laststat`.  It will be, however, be from 0-5 seconds stale.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vmstat

```
rbabchis@haze:~$ vmstat 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 333020 308684 1609404    0    0    20    21    5    9  2  2 96  0  0
 0  0      0 332392 308692 1609560    0    0    26    38 1655 4276  4  1 95  0  0
 0  0      0 332228 308692 1609588    0    0     6    30 1731 4381  4  2 95  0  0
```

It looks like you need "vmstat 5 2" to give you an average just once. I don't think the first line counts.

```
rbabchis@haze:~$ vmstat 5 2 
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 315632 309116 1615048    0    0    20    21    5   10  2  2 96  0  0
 0  0      0 335676 309128 1615056    0    0     0    54 1861 5291  3  3 94  0  0
```

Comment: `vmstat 5 2` also have 5 seconds delay, the same as `mpstat 5 1`

Comment: Yeah woops... you'll need something recording constantly to get that info when needed.